# finding the phase angle of a signal - solving a non-linear (trigonometric) system of equations

Tags: matlab, octave, trigonometry, maxima, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to calculate the **phase2 angle/value in the y2 equation** of a signal given at a specific frequency if I know the other values.  Is this possible?  Example below: along with picture example:

[image: Trying to find phase2 of y2]

```
y1=A1*cos*(2*pi*f1*t+phase1)   we know A1,f1,t=1,phase1
y1=0.00720858*cos*(2*pi*6+6.33)

y2=A2*cos*(2*pi*f2*t+phase2)  we know A2,f2,t=1, trying to find **phase2** 
y2=.4*cos*(2*pi*6.4951+phase2)

y3=A3*cos*(2*pi*f3*t+phase3) we know A3,f3,t=1,phase3  
y3=0.0135274*cos(2*pi*7+.786473)
```

I'm using maxima 13.04.2, octave 3.8.1.

I tried to solve the **y2 equation for phase2** in maxima but it got rid of the cos function

```
kill(all);
A:A; phase:phase; solve(A*cos*(2*pi*t+phase)=0,phase);
```

the answer came back as **phase=-2pi*t**

Is this possible? or should I go about this another way?
Thanks

Comment: Rick, when you say you have 1000's of these equations, can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean the equations have the same form, but different coefficients? or that the equations all have different forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weird result might stem from the fact that you *multiply* the `cos` function with what is supposed to be its argument (by the way, this is mathematically unsound). What you might want is to *apply* the `cos` function to the argument. To illustrate what I mean, compare:

```
A*cos*(2*pi*t+phase)
```

with:

```
A*cos(2*pi*t+phase)
```

On another hand, why not solve the equation pen-on-paper style?

> *y*<sub>2</sub> = *A*<sub>2</sub>×cos(2π*f*<sub>2</sub>*t* + φ<sub>2</sub>)   ⇒
>
> *y*<sub>2</sub>/*A*<sub>2</sub> = cos(2π*f*<sub>2</sub>*t* + φ<sub>2</sub>)   ⇒
>
> arccos(*y*<sub>2</sub>/*A*<sub>2</sub>) = 2π*f*<sub>2</sub>*t* + φ<sub>2</sub>   ⇒
>
> arccos(*y*<sub>2</sub>/*A*<sub>2</sub>) - 2π*f*<sub>2</sub>*t* = φ<sub>2</sub>

With the values that you provided:

> *A*<sub>2</sub> = 0.4, *f*<sub>2</sub> = 6.4951, *t* = 1.

you can calculate the phase φ<sub>2</sub> as function of your level *y*<sub>2</sub> (left as exercise to you).

Comment: Pen and paper is nice but if you have 1000's of these equations it's best to use a computer :-) .  I'm not sure what you mean by "you multiply the cos function with what is supposed to be it's argument"  I plan on using maxima to solve these equations is the syntax not correct?

Comment: @RickT I updated my answer to illustrate what I mean. I agree also partially with your 1000-equations point of view. However, if all equations look the same, the probability of *subtly* screwing something up increases linearly with the number of equations when using a computer (because you need to input 1000 equations, and you can make a mistake on every input). Meanwhile, when solving pen-on-paper an equation that has 1000 instances, you either get it right for all, or not, which is far easier to figure out.